# jQuery UI 1.7.1 Modal Close on Overlay Click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to override the default behavior of a jQuery UI modal dialog box to close the box when the overlay is clicked.  The code I have below will close the dialog box after I open it for the first time and click on the overlay.  When I open the dialog box again, clicking on the overlay does nothing.  I am missing an event here.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

```
$(function(){

        $('#production_schedule_dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 570,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true
        }); 

        $('#production_schedule_dialog_link').click(function(){
            $('#production_schedule_dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $(document).bind('click', dialogBlur);
});


var dialogBlur = function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('.ui-dialog') || target.parents('.ui-dialog').length) {
        return;
    }

    $('.ui-dialog:visible').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').trigger('click');

    $(document).unbind('click', dialogBlur);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Easiest way to do it:
http://www.ryanjeffords.com/blog/entry/closing-a-jquery-ui-dialog-when-the-dialog-loses-focus

Add this:

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function() {
    //Close the dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

Comment: .live() is deprecated, use .on() instead.

Comment: There can be multiple dialogs on single page with different id's. So you can close the dialog using such id.

Answer (score 10):

Paul's solution works fine if you're using an old version of jQuery (pre-1.7). Now `.live()` is deprecated though. Try using `on()` instead.

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').on("click", function() {
    //Close the dialog
    $(this).find(".dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

Comment: The '.ui-widget-overly' is dynamically created. You need to be sure the element exists before adding this lines. A better approach would be to add the event on the document: `$(document).on('click', function() { $('.dialog').dialog("close"); });`

Comment: Yes, `.ui-widget-overly` is dynamically created, so this code won't necessarily be bound when required. I resolved this by putting it within the `open()` event of the dialog, so it binds AFTER `.ui-widget-overly` is created. Assigning a `click` event to the entire document may be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working, but I took it, modified it, and got a version that seems to work as both you and I want:

```
var openDialogWindow = function(dialogId)
 {

     $(dialogId).dialog('open');
     $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click", closeDialogWindowOnOverlayClick);
 }

 var closeDialogWindowOnOverlayClick = function(event){
     var closeButton = $(".ui-dialog:visible").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
     closeButton.trigger("click");
     $(".ui-widget-overlay").unbind("click", closeDialogWindowOnOverlayClick);
 }
```

The major difference here is that I'm binding dialog-closing logic to clicks on JQuery's overlay object (instead of the document, as you are). And I do the binding when the dialog opens and unbinding it when the dialog closes. Not truly necessary, but it keeps things clean.

Regardless, thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: I tried like 5 different ways this is the only one I was able to get working (and the cleanest) through the dialog's built in 'open' event. I defined a defaultDialogOptions variable with $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind("click", closeDialogWindowOnOverlayClick); inside the 'open' event callback and I derive all my site-wide dialogs from this setting aka $('<div></div>').dialog($.extend({}, defualtSettings, { /*specific settings*/ })); Works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do it :

```
$('body').on("click", ".ui-widget-overlay", function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    });
```

Comment: Why not just attach the event to `.ui-widget-overlay`? Why are you creating an event that will be permanently stuck to the body for something that's not permanently there?

Comment: because ui-widget-overlay is dynamically created though attach it on the body isn't a good idea either

Answer (score 1):

looking at your example it looks like you are unbinding the event and not setting it back up.

try moving your bind call:

```
    $('#production_schedule_dialog_link').click(function(){
            $('#production_schedule_dialog').dialog('open');
            $(document).bind('click', dialogBlur);
            return false;
    });
```

that should rebind your blur listener each time your dialog is opened.

Answer (score 1):

If page contains few dialogs, you can use this universal method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-widget-overlay', function() {
  var $dialog = $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog:visible')
    .find('.ui-dialog-content');
  if ($dialog.length && $dialog.dialog('isOpen')) {
    $dialog.dialog('close');
  }
});
```

Comment: Just replace "siblings" with "next" and it will work with multiple open dialogs too..

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I have many different types of dialog box, so adding code to every one seemed silly. This should be the top answer! Pretty much paste-and-go. Thanks, mysterious one-point anonymous user!

Answer (score 0):

This post may help:

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/16/jquery-modal-dialog-close-on-overlay-click/

Answer (score 0):

So many complicated answers... here is a simple reusable one.

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function(event)
{
    $(this).prev().find('div:nth-child(2)').dialog('close');
});
```