# jQuery UI modal dialog closes on clicking itself

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a modal popup in my page which closes itself when I click on any control in that dialog, below is the code:

```
function overlayclickclose() {
    if (closedialog) {
        jQuery('#mydialog').dialog('close');
    }
}
closedialog = 1;

jQuery('#mydialog').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 400,
    resizable: false,
    open: function() {
        closedialog = 1;
        jQuery(document).bind('click', overlayclickclose);
    },
    focus: function() {
        closedialog = 1;
    },
    close: function() {
        jQuery(document).unbind('click');
    }
});
```

When I click on that modal dialog anywhere, it closes so I can not operate on it. How can I fix it?

Note that my div is in an update panel and puts a user control of [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) Inside.

Comment: My question is when i click on that modal dialog anywhere it closes so ican not operate on it

Comment: focus: function() {
        closedialog = 1;
    }                                              TO                                   focus: function() {
        closedialog = 0;
    } worked for mw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know why the dialog is closing as soon as you click anywhere in your dialog. You have added a `.click()` event listener to the whole document, every time a click occurs, it will run your callback function `overlayclickclose()`.

That is checking to see if you want to close the dialog:

```
if (closedialog)
```

As `closedialog` is always `1` which as a boolean is **true** any click anywhere will close the dialog. Your function will basically say `if (true)` do something, so will always 'do something'.

If you change your focus event to:

```
closedialog = 0;
```

Close dialog is now `0` which as a boolean is **flase** so the dialog wont close.

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsEH9/)

[**See it not working as you have it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsEH9/1/)

---

After a quick search, it looks like the code you are using is something very similar to [**this tutorial**](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/06/16/jquery-modal-dialog-close-on-overlay-click/) - see the use of `1` and `0` for the `closedialog` variable.

---

There is another way you can do this, its probably easier to follow in code. [See the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092940/jquery-ui-1-7-1-modal-close-on-overlay-click). You can change your code to something like this:

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    resizable: false
});

$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function() {
    $('#mydialog').dialog('close');
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xsEH9/2/)

Comment: No problem at all. Could you mark it as the accepted answer - tick the hollow tick to the top left of the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "why does this dialog close when elements inside of it are clicked?", then the answer is that the click events from the sub-elements are propagating to the parent element. See *[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)* for details of how to stop this happening. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nathan,Would you please put an example i did not get that link properly or would you suggest where should i include stop propogation method in my code